# why does my vscode dont override user setting?(my workspace setting doenst work?)

Tags: visual-studio-code

so i basically set auto-save-off, tab-size-8 in workspace setting in the vscode.
and when i open my html file in workspace 'index.html' it doesn't apply as workspace setting but user setting in the vscode editor.
auto-save-on.focus, tab-size-2

I searched google about workspace and seems like nobody is really interested in my problem..

i don't know why my workspace setting doesn't override user setting.
any solution to actually imply workspace setting rather than user setting?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with file:Autosave. In Vscode workspace setting has preferences over user settings, but it seems that if the workspace is the default and it is not explicitly saved to the settings.json in the workspace.vs-code directory to the default "off" the user setting "afterDelay" overrides the workspace setting.